# How can I make my footer full width?

Tags: css

For some reason the footer on one page of my site is not full width. There's a huge white space on the left that I cannot seem to get rid of and its causing my entire footer to be shifted to the right.

This is the current CSS:

```
#main-footer {
width: 105%;
margin-bottom: -50px;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
height: auto;
padding: 50px;
background-color: #2E2E2E;
}

#top-footer {
height: 30px;
background-color: #77CAE9;
margin-left: 0;
width: 105%;
}
```

I have a feeling it's related to the page width but I can't figure out where to adjust that either. I'll be so grateful if someone can help me out with this!

EDIT: The URL to the page is http://tstand.com/blog

Thanks :)

Angela

Comment: You should provide a JSFiddle so people can see the problem.

Comment: There may be some padding added to the container of the footer on this page. Set the padding to the container of the footer to `0` and set the margin to be `0` as well.

Comment: The blog-spot.css line 11 has margin-left: -45px; remove it and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with moving your `<footer>` outside of the `<div class="container">`.

The class `.container` is used to centre it's content in middle of the screen. See more details here here:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: I am glad it helped. If you are happy with the answer please accept it :)

Comment: Angela, its been a while but could you accept this answer is resolved your issue please?

Comment: Hi Richard, I would love to but how can I do that?

Comment: Looks like you found it Angela, thank you. When possible you should always accept correct answers to help future visitors. ;)

Answer (score 0):

A common cause for this can be a default `padding` or `margin` of `<body>` or even `<html>`. In that case CSS like this should fix it:

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
```

If the problem persists please post a complete, but minimal example that demonstrates the issue.